# HDF5 to Dataframe format

Tags: python, dataframe, hdf5

I am bit new to python. Could someone help me to get the command to convert HDF5 file to dataframe.
I converted the dataframe to HDF5 file using

```
    hdf = pd.HDFStore('hdf5_name.h5')
    hdf.put('hdf', dataframe)
    hdf.close()
```

Now I wish to get back the dataframe. So what should I do?

Comment: Have you tried [pandas.read_hdf](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.read_hdf.html) ?

Comment: @jpp Sure thanks! I got it!